# How to Merge Data Column from One Oracle Database into Another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `Order` and `Intend`.

`Order` table with sample data:

```
oano code slno 
---------------
1808 ln    1
1808 lk    2
1808 lc    3
1809 ki    1 
1809 dl    2
```

`Intend` table with sample data:

```
Intendno Oano code slno
------------------------
I/1      1808  ln
I/1      1808  lc
I/2      1809  ki
I/3      1809  dl
```

I want to merge `slno` data from `Order` table into `Intend` table, as shown below:

```
Intendno Oano code slno
-----------------------
I/1      1808  ln   1
I/1      1808  lc   3
I/2      1809  ki   1
I/3      1809  dl   2
```

How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution using `merge`:

```
MERGE INTO Intend target
USING (select oano, code, max(slno) slno
           from "Order"
           group by oano, code
      ) source
ON
(target.code = source.code and target.Oano = source.Oano 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET target.slno= source.slno;
```

Comment: showing error ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: You are probably having multiple matches in `Order` table for a record in `Intend` Table. Answer was updated using `group by` it now merges the `max` of  `slno` for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can try updating using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Intend i
SET slno = (SELECT o.slno FROM "Order" o WHERE i.Oano = o.oano AND i.code = o.code);
```

Note that naming a table `Order`, which is a reserved keyword in SQL, is a generally bad idea, because it means you will have to escape that table name whenever you refer to it.

Comment: It is showing error single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Your sample data does not reveal this problem.  So, maybe you should update your question with the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an inner join

```
with "Order"(oano, code,slno) as
(
 select 1808,'ln',1 from dual union all
 select 1808,'lk',2 from dual union all
 select 1808,'lc',3 from dual union all
 select 1809,'ki',1 from dual union all 
 select 1809,'dl',2 from dual
), Intend(Intendno, Oano, code) as
(
 select 'I/1',1808,'ln' from dual union all
 select 'I/1',1808,'lc' from dual union all
 select 'I/2',1809,'ki' from dual union all
 select 'I/3',1809,'dl' from dual
)
select i.*, o.slno 
  from Intend i
  join "Order" o
    on o.Oano = i.Oano 
       and o.code = i.code;

 INTENDNO OANO CODE SLNO
 -------- ---- ---- ----
 I/1      1808  ln   1
 I/1      1808  lc   3
 I/2      1809  ki   1
 I/3      1809  dl   2
```

to list the desired results.

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/JFXYA22219)</kbd>